# No Audio in USB headset in Android 12 base device (Android S) -- 2nd Whatsup audio call case

Tags: android, usb, libusb

**Use case** :

**Pre-cond** : Connect USB headset to Android 12 based device

1.) Initiate what's up audio call
**Result **: 2way audio is fine

2.) Initiate/Receive audio call
**Result **: 1way audio is present (Output : Audio via USB MIC , Input : NONE )

**Log snippets (after disconnecting 1st whats up audio call) :**
04-11 06:01:25.761   307  2667 E modules.usbaudio.audio_hal: start_output_stream failed to open device(card: 0 device: 0)
04-11 06:01:25.769   307  2667 E modules.usbaudio.audio_hal: start_output_stream failed to open device(card: 0 device: 0)
04-11 06:01:25.776   307  2667 E modules.usbaudio.audio_hal: start_output_stream failed to open device(card: 0 device: 0)

Expected result :
2way audio should be established in USB headset during audio call.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.